# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown is Not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

Hi so im creating a Bootstrap 3 website but my dropdown dosnt seem to be working on my navbar, Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Joosh - Welcome</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Linking CSS Stylesheets -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/customStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>
        
    <!-- Navigation Bar Top - Open -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Joosh</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Social Media <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navigation Bar Top - Closed -->
    
      <!-- Linking JavaScript Resources -->
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"</script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ive tried placeing the JavaScript into the head but that still dosnt seem to work. Any ideas on what the problem is, i also tried getting the jquery from the googleapi's website and jquerys website.

Comment: Your code works on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XDwHSae4Vc) so it's most likely the paths to your files that are wrong. Are there any 404's in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the issue:

You're missing a ">"

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"</script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```